# Angle between moon's north node and mars in PyEphem

Tags: python, pyephem

I am curious how to compute the angle between the Moon's north node and Mars for any given day using `PyEphem`. For instance, in `PyEphem`, one can directly compute the angle between the moon and mars with the following:

```
print(ephem.separation(ephem.Moon("2016-01-02"),ephem.Mars("2016-01-02")))
```

But the question arises for the Moon's north node and Mars.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.